Regarding WebSockets
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected to socket.io");

    socket.on("setup", (userData) => {
        socket.join(userData._id);
        socket.emit("connected");
    });

    socket.on("join chat", (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log("User Joined Room: " + room);
    });

    socket.on("typing", (room) => socket.in(room).emit("typing"));
    socket.on("stop typing", (room) => socket.in(room).emit("stop typing"));

    socket.on("new message", (newMessageRecieved) => {
        var chat = newMessageRecieved.chat;

        if (!chat.users) return console.log("chat.users not defined");

        chat.users.forEach((user) => {
            if (user._id == newMessageRecieved.sender._id) return;

            socket.in(user._id).emit("message recieved", newMessageRecieved);
        });
    });
});

Alice logs in, the "setup" event triggers, and she is added to a private room having roomId as her userId (let's say, 123).
When Alice clicks on some chat, the "join chat" event triggers, and she is added to another room having roomId as the chatId (chatId represents the ID of that particular chat model).
Now, when Alice tries to send a message, let's say to a single user or group depending on the chat she clicked on, the "new message" event triggers, gets access to the users array and sends the message to the users within the array except for the sender using the "UserID", which will give access to the private room created by the "setup" event.
So, if there are 3 users, ie it is a group chat, messages will be sent to them and displayed on the UI. But then, what was the need to create the "join chat" event? Because we are sending messages based on userId room which is created in "setup" and not "join chat". But if I comment "join chat", messages are not sent in real time, then I need to reload the server.
Can anyone explain to me the code and flow?

Presumably newMessageRecieved.chat is whatever room Alice is sending the message to, ie her private chat room or the group chat room. So, if she sends a message to the group chat, and the "join chat" event is commented out, then there would be no users in the group chat's users array and so the message would have nowhere to go. Why is that confusing?
